# Is there a good maths specific dictionary for LaTeX?

Tags: dictionaries

I just wanted to know if there is a good dictionary I can download for the custom LaTeX dictionaries.

I know that I can edit the existing ones easily and use, for example, ones from OpenOffice to start with. But having to add all the standard mathematical terminology seems like a drag.

Is there a custom dictionary available out there that has most of the standard mathematical terms in it?

Comment: Which tool do you use for spell-checking? The built-in tool for a particular editor? Or some `aspell`/`ispell`-related tool?

Comment: Sry for the the late replay. I use the build in one. I am just looking for a simple dictionary file.

Comment: Then we need to know which editor you use.

Comment: MIktex. It has the .dic text files as dictionary, also found for open office. It is very easy to edit and indeed I once tried to just add all the math-vocabuary myself. Problem is that I lost that file and was wondering if someting like that didnt float around somewhere on the web, since it does seem pretty useful.

Comment: Does this help: http://www.jpetrie.net/scientific-word-list-for-spell-checkersspelling-dictionaries/ ?

Comment: To some degree yes. Indeed thats exactly the type of thing I was looking for. But unforutunately its not very mathematic I guess. Simple terms like homomorphism, surjective, module, category etc. for example are not there. I dont mean to be unappreciative, but if someone knows a more mathematical (algebra more exactly) one, it would be nice if it woule be posted. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I found none, so I started creating one while writing my thesis. Please contribute the words that you're using in your math papers!

https://github.com/marmistrz/mathdictionary

Comment: Mine. CC0. https://gist.github.com/Symbol1/2fe480438e153d8d69c2a374fbede4ce